# pyspark merge/join two data frame

Tags: join, merge, pyspark

I want to merge two data frame.

list 1:

```
      id        
0   1234
1   456
2   789
3   101112
```

list 2:

```
      id    age        
0   456      18
1   101112   52
```

Desired result:

```
      id    age     
0   1234     Na
1   456      18
2   789      Na
3   101112   52
```

tried:

```
list1.join(list2,list1.id==list2.id,'inner')
```

error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

tried:

```
list1.merge(list2)
```

error:

result is list 2.

what is the problem?

Comment: what you require is a left join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to perform a `left_outer` join so it doesn't drop records

```
list3 = list1.join(list2, 'id', 'left_outer')
list3.show()

+------+----+
|    id| age|
+------+----+
|   789|null|
|  1234|null|
|101112|  52|
|   456|  18|
+------+----+
```

Comment: can you post the exact code you ran? the code sample I gave in the answer works as-is. also, the docs on `join` are here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join

Answer (score 2):

If you have two `dataframe`s as

```
list1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1234,), (456,), (789,), (101112,)], ["id"])
list1.show()
+------+
|    id|
+------+
|  1234|
|   456|
|   789|
|101112|
+------+
```

and

```
list2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(456,18), (101112, 52)], ["id", "age"])
list2.show()
+------+---+
|    id|age|
+------+---+
|   456| 18|
|101112| 52|
+------+---+
```

A `left join` should give you your desired result

```
list1.join(list2, "id", "left").show()

+------+----+
|    id| age|
+------+----+
|   789|null|
|  1234|null|
|101112|  52|
|   456|  18|
+------+----+
```